# What is the best way to populate base properties?

Tags: c#, inheritance

I'm wondering if someone can help me with what is the best way to populate the base properties of a derived class. I would like to use one method to populate the properties of the base whether the base or the child is being used.

Here is an example of what I am asking:

```
public class Parent
{
     public string Id {get; set;}
}

public class Child : Parent
{
     public string Name {get; set;}
}

public Parent GetParent(int ID)
{
     Parent myParent = new Parent();
//Lookup and populate
return Parent;
}

public Child GetChild(string name)
{
Child myChild = new Child();

//Use the GetParent method to populate base items
//and then  
//Lookup and populate Child properties

return myChild;
}
```

Comment: populate via constructor?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Populate base class along with child class?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3649354/populate-base-class-along-with-child-class)

Comment: you can do what `sll` has suggested or you can take the Inheritance route..

Comment: Don't forget constructor chaining.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you might be overcomplicating things a bit. Take a look at this code that uses inheritance and constructors to initialize objects:

```
public class Parent
{
    public string Id {get; set;}

    public Parent(string id)
    {
        Id = id;
    }
}

public class Child : Parent
{
    public string Name {get; set;}

    public Child(string id, string name) : base(id) // <-- call base constructor
    {
        Name = name;
    }
}
```

It uses constructors for initialization and the [base keyword](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hfw7t1ce%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) to call the parent constructor from the derived class. I would go this direction unless you really need to have a factory method construct your object.

Answer (score 2):

Something like this if you don't  want to do it in `constructor`.

Note: the `constructor` is not always called, especially if the type is desirialized using certain serializators.

```
public class Parent
{

     public string Id {get; set;}

     public virtual void InitPorperties() {
        //init properties of base
     }

}


public class Child : Base {

    public override void InitProperties() {
        //init Child properties
        base.InitProperties();
    }
}
```

After this you can use it like:

```
public Parent GetParent(int ID)
{
     var myParent = new Parent();
     parent.InitProperties();
     return myParent;
}

public Parent GetChild(int ID)
{
     var  child= new Child();
     child.InitProperties();
     return child;
}
```

As anything it has other side of coin: the caller has to call `InitProperties` method in oder to get correctly initialized object.

If the serialization/desialization is not a concern in your case, stick with constructors, in practice call this methods inside ctors of every type (`Parent`, `Child`)

Answer (score 1):

If you dont want to use a standard way to just

```
   Child myChild = new Child();
    myChild.Name = "name";
    myChild.Id = "1";
```

You can populate them via the constructor like this.

```
    public class Parent
    {
        public Parent(string id)
        {
            Id = id;
        }

        public string Id { get; set; }
    }

    public class Child : Parent
    {
        public Child(string id, string name)
            : base(id)
        {
            name = Name;
        }

        public string Name { get; set; }
    }
```

And when you isntanciate it

```
     Child myChild = new Child("1", "name");
```

Which in my opinion is a quite neat way to do it.